# Jsoup posting modified Document

Tags: java, screen-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to create a web scraper for my coming android app. Therefore I need to use a simple search form on a website, fill it out and send my results back to the server.

As mentioned in the [Jsoup-Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes), I scraped the site I needed from the Server and changed the values.

Now I just need to post my modified document back to the server and scrape the resulting page.
As far as I've seen in the Jsoup-API there is no way to post something back, except with the `.data-Attribute` in Jsoup.connection, which is unfortunately not able to fill out text fields by their id.

Any ideas or workarounds, how to post the modified document, or its parts back to the website ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how HTTP works in general. It is not true that the *entire* HTML document with modified input values is been sent from the client to the server. It's more so that the name=value pairs of all input elements are been sent as request parameters. The server will return the desired HTML response then.

For example, if you want to simulate a submit of the following form in Jsoup (you can find the exact HTML form syntax by opening the page with the form in your browser and do a rightclick, *View Source*)

```html
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/somescript">
    <input type="text" name="text1" />
    <input type="text" name="text2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="hidden1value" />
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Other button" />
</form>
```

then you need to construct the request as follows:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/somescript")
    .data("text1", "yourText1Value") // Fill the first input field.
    .data("text2", "yourText2Value") // Fill the second input field.
    .data("hidden1", "hidden1value") // You need to keep it unmodified!
    .data("button1", "Submit")       // This way the server knows which button was pressed.
    .post();

// ...
```

In some cases you'd also need to send the session cookies back, but that's a subject apart (and a question which has already been asked several times here before; in general, it's easier to use a real HTTP client for this and pass its response through `Jsoup#parse()`).

#### See also:

- [HTTP tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/index.htm)
- [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried to input my data with the `.data-Attribute` but I'd ran into the problem, that there is no name for the submit-Button specified, so I don't know how to send the request correctly, to get to the next page.

Comment: If the submit button doesn't have a name, just skip it. The server apparently doesn't need it.

Comment: Thanks again BalusC
I guess there is a need to interact with the button somehow. I tested a few sites with lynx for the cookie-less searching and they all worked well, but I can't get the same result by using my scraper.
Because I denied all cookies, as I used lynx from the bash, I don't think, that is has sth. to do with the cookies, but with the submit-action or -button

Comment: It's hard to help you without detail about the problem which you currently have.

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem. Because I used wrong names for the parameters I requested for the server. Your description 100% practical and true.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way. You should create a POST request (use Apache HTTP Components), get the response and then scrape it with JSoup.

Comment: I tried also this method, but in my opinion it takes too long to get a response for an application for mobile devices.